# Replaying Mission 45 [MGSV SPOILERS]

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

> The most recent patch for MGSV allows you to bring Quiet back by playing Mission 11 - Cloaked in Silence 7 times in a row.

I've got her back now and am currently going back through the game to complete all of the side objectives. If I replay Mission 45 - A Quiet Exit to do the side objectives, will she leave again?

Comment: You might want to add first sentence into spoiler tag - I know the title says there are spoilers, but the preview of the question on the list may spoil some things for others. Also good to hear that one can bring Quiet back, I like her :)

Comment: @Asunez Good point - Spoiler tag added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the butterfly emblem and scored her staying. I dare not try it without, though. So unless you're feeling froggy, I wouldn't suggest it. As far as survivability tactics: use the armor parasites and your strongest rocket launcher. You don't need to kill the grunts, just the armor.

Comment: Thanks :) I think I'll do the same - Equip the butterfly just for redoing this mission for the side objectives.